# How do I change the primary-color value in less?

Tags: css, less

How do I change the primary-color value in less? I write it down but it doesn't work

```
@primary-color: red;
.header {@primary-color: blue;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must Change Code to This

```
@primary-color: backgound-color;
.header {@{primary-color}: blue;}
```

OR

```
@primary-color: red;
.header {background-color: @primary-color;}
```

i think you want this

```
@primary-color: red;
.header { @primary-color:blue;}
 p{
   .header();
   color:@primary-color;
}
```